# add unbound/custom field to a form in Symfony 5 - Can't get a way to read the property "extra" in class "App\Entity\

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I want to add an extra fiel to a form, in Symfony, but it won't accept it if it's not bound to an entity attribute.

If someone knows what I can do to fix it, many thanks in advance !

Here is the formtype, I'm trying to add the "extra" field :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Dossier;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class InscriptionBCType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {

        $builder
            ->add('extra', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Les besoins qui motivent votre demande (soyez exhaustif)',
                'required' => false,
                ])
            ->add('Nom')
            ->add('Prenom')
            ->add('Mail')
            ->add('civilite', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => [
                    'Monsieur' => "Monsieur",
                    'Madame' => "Madame",
                ],
            ])            ->add('telephone')
            ->add('adresse')
            ->add('code_postal')
            ->add('ville')
            ->add('projet', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'votre projet entrepreneurial (SI VOUS EN AVEZ UN)(FACULTATIF)',
                'required' => false,
                ])
            ->add('besoin', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Les besoins qui motivent votre demande (soyez exhaustif)',
                'required' => false,
                ])
            ->add('budgetCPF', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Votre budget CPF mobilisable',
                'required' => false,
                ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Dossier::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And I get this error :

```
Can't get a way to read the property "extra" in class "App\Entity\Dossier".
```

Comment: did you define ```extra``` in your entity and push it to your database?

Comment: That's what i'm trying not to do : I want my form to have this extra field, unbound to the entity. This field is specific to this particular form, and will be processed differently in the controller. I don't want to pollute my entity with it because it's not going to be saved in the database, this field will affect how the POST request will be treated in the controller but not be a part of the entity attributes

Comment: did you try to add an mapped option and set it to false? example ``` "add(extra" => 'file', array("mapped" => false))```

Comment: Thanks ! This was it ! I added "mapped=>false'" in the field options and now it works perfectly ! Thank you very much =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I already answered the question in the comments but not everyone reads them this is why I am posting it as an answer,if you want a field to be ignored you have to use [mapped](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped) for example:

`add("extra"=> 'file', array("mapped"=>false))`